# Android Push Notifications

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have a news website and i'm developing an android app that gets the news articles from a url as JSON and everything is working well. Now i want to implement push notifications in the android app, so whenever a new article is published a notification with the article's title appears on the android device screen. (like facebook).

I made some research and i found that i have to use Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) but it's not that easy to implement, is there any easy-to-follow tutorial about that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read here about it, should be pretty straight forward:
https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html

also you can follow this: 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rmzv716SYkQ

and send specific errors you encounter during the process.

Comment: Thanks for the video tutorial!

Comment: the tutorial uses an old GCM technique, i think we should stick to the new one right ?

Answer (score 2):

[Parse](https://parse.com/) is a very good solution, it is very easy to implement and you get unlimited number of push with the free service up to 1 million users (last time i checked)

Comment: Thank you but i'll try implementing it manually and if i couldn't i'll use Parse. :)